# Помогите написать java doc для класса

Tags: java, javadoc

Есть написанный класс дженерик адаптер

```
public abstract class CustomAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {....}
```

Помогите написать для него java doc. Надо чтобы комментарий не содержал того, что видно из сигнатуры класса.

Я пытался описать в java doc, что он нужен для работы с любым типом данных, но сказали что это видно из сигнатуры. И добавляют что вот коммент не раскрывает назначение класса.

Коммент должен отвечать на вопросы : назначение класса?зачем этот класс нужен?почему я его создал?

Изначально был: "Обобщенная базовая реализация {@link BaseAdapter}. Позволяет подклассам указывать тип данных в виде параметра {@link T}"

Comment: Какой комент был у вас изначально?

Comment: Вопросы хорошие на самом деле. Для чего используется класс? Зачем Вы его создали? Откуда нам это знать?